# using XmlArrayItem attribute without XmlArray on Serializable C# class

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, serializable, xml-deserialization

I want XML in the following format:

```
<configuration><!-- Only one configuration node -->
  <logging>...</logging><!-- Only one logging node -->
  <credentials>...</credentials><!-- One or more credentials nodes -->
  <credentials>...</credentials>
</configuration>
```

I'm trying to create a class `Configuration` that has the `[Serializable]` attribute.  To serialize the credentials nodes, I have the following:

```
[XmlArray("configuration")]
[XmlArrayItem("credentials", typeof(CredentialsSection))]
public List<CredentialsSection> Credentials { get; set; }
```

However, when I serialize this to XML, the XML is in the following format:

```
<configuration>
  <logging>...</logging>
  <configuration><!-- Don't want credentials nodes nested in a second
                      configuration node -->
    <credentials>...</credentials>
    <credentials>...</credentials>
  </configuration>
</configuration>
```

If I remove the `[XmlArray("configuration")]` line, I get the following:

```
<configuration>
  <logging>...</logging>
  <Credentials><!-- Don't want credentials nodes nested in Credentials node -->
    <credentials>...</credentials>
    <credentials>...</credentials>
  </Credentials>
</configuration>
```

How can I serialize this the way I want, with multiple `<credentials>` nodes within the single root node `<configuration>`?  I wanted to do this without having to implement `IXmlSerializable` and do custom serialization.  This is how my class is described:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("configuration")]
public class Configuration : IEquatable<Configuration>
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The following should serialize properly the way you want. The clue being `[XmlElement("credentials")]` on the list. I did this by taking your xml, generating a schema (xsd) from it in Visual Studio. Then running xsd.exe on the schema to generate a class. (And some small edits)

```
public class CredentialsSection
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class configuration
{
    /// <remarks/>
    public string logging { get; set; }

    /// <remarks/>
    [XmlElement("credentials")]
    public List<CredentialsSection> credentials { get; set; }

    public string Serialize()
    {
        var credentialsSection = new CredentialsSection {Username = "a", Password = "b"};
        this.credentials = new List<CredentialsSection> {credentialsSection, credentialsSection};
        this.logging = "log this";
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        TextWriter w = new StringWriter(sb);
        s.Serialize(w, this);
        w.Flush();
        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

give the following output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<configuration xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <logging>log this</logging>
  <credentials>
    <Username>a</Username>
    <Password>b</Password>
  </credentials>
  <credentials>
    <Username>a</Username>
    <Password>b</Password>
  </credentials>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yep, that worked!  I was so set on "it's a `List`, gotta use the `XmlArrayItem` attribute somewhere" that I didn't even think of making it a regular `XmlElement`.

Comment: good answer, i had the same problem - i wanted to remove:
<DATAITEMS> 
  <DATAITEM/>
  <DATAITEM/>
</ DATAITEMS>

resolved it with:
        [XmlElement("DATAITEM")]
        public List<string> DATAITEM { get; set; }

Comment: Thanks Mikael.  This helped me out with my problem today. +1

Comment: It works only when using XmlSerializer. It doesn't work when used inside a WCF DataContract, in a WCF DataMember, like `[XmlElement("credentials")]
        [DataMember]
        public List<CredentialsSection> credentials { get; set; }`. It seems like WCF ignores the Xml* attributes for serialization. Any suggestion?

Comment: @natenho Correct. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591907/how-can-you-control-net-datacontract-serialization-so-it-uses-xml-attributes-in for more insight into this.

Comment: thanks a lot ! That was killing me all the XmlArray , XmlArrayItem,  ... The answer was so simple easy.