# Serializing List<> with XmlSerializer

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I have defined the following classes.

**Document.cs**

```
public class Document {
  // ...
  [XmlAttribute]
  public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

**DocumentOrder.cs**

```
public class DocumentOrder {
  // ...
  [XmlAttribute]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public List<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

When serializing this to an XML I get:

```
<DocumentOrder Name="myname">
  <Documents>
    <Document Status="new"/>
    // ...
  </Documents>
</DocumentOrder>
```

But I would like to have it like that, i.e. be the `Document` elements to be children of `DocumentOrder`.

```
<DocumentOrder Name="myname">
  <Document Status="new"/>
  <Document Status="new"/>
  <Document Status="new"/>
  // The document element has other attributes to distinguish...
</DocumentOrder>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303165/using-xmlarrayitem-attribute-without-xmlarray-on-serializable-c-sharp-class) answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try :

```
public class DocumentOrder {
  // ...
  [XmlAttribute]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  [XmlElement("Document")]
  public List<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Should just be a case of:

```
public class DocumentOrder {
  // ...
  [XmlAttribute]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [XmlArrayItem("Document")]
  public List<Document> Documents { get; set; }
}
```

There are some [good examples on MSDN on what the various XML serialization attributes do](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z.aspx)

Comment: doesn't this still create the `<Documents>` tag?