# C# How to serialize mutiple classes (from object)

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

It's silverlight project. I have the following XML :

```
<pars>
    <par>            
    </par>

    <s>Auto1</s>

    <par>           
    </par>      

    <par>
    </par>
</pars>
```

As you can see there are two `Parameter` (Under `Parameters`) and are one `seperators` .

All of them comes under `Parameters` in xml (And Parameters.cs in c# code).

**What i am trying to do ?**
I have Following C# classes corresponding to that xml (Using the object of Parameters.cs class i am again trying to obtain the same xml).

Comment: take a look at this one   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303165/using-xmlarrayitem-attribute-without-xmlarray-on-serializable-c-sharp-class

Comment: @Jakub Thanks for the link but i dont have to use any inbuilt thing of Visual Studio. I have to make changesin my code in order to show the similar xml. Could you pleasehlp me in doing this ??

Comment: This `[XmlElement("parameter")] public List<Parameter> Parameter { get; set; }` is not valid annotation for a list. You should use something like: `[XmlArray("parameterList")] [XmlArrayItem("parameter", typeof(Parameter))]` instead.

Comment: @rosko i have debugged it and this c# classed are working for deserialisation of xml that i have given at starting in code aand object is showing both xml name and values for each element on debugging for all <parameter> and <seperator> and it is working and i have to use

Answer (score 0):

First, i'm not sure that you need a construtor in the Parameters.cs and Parameter.cs, you could remove them.

Secondly, could you send us what is different between both xml ? Is it just the header ?

Try to change your serialization by this :

```
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            //Serialization
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ClassToSerialize));
            xs.Serialize(ms, ObjectToSerialize);
            ms.Position = 0;

            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load(ms);
        }
```

Comment: I removed constructor and i have edited the snapshot of the output obtained on debugging. Its just that i have whown to you, I dont knbow why.

Comment: and its still same on removing constructor.

Comment: Yes the sentence for the construtor was just to say that is useless :) . The classes seems correct, could you try to change

Comment: Change what  ? in my class ?

Comment: How would complier know thta which Parameter element belongs to which <parameter> in xml ?

Comment: Yes the sentence for the construtor was just to say that is useless :) . The classes seems correct, could you try to change your xmlroot `code`[XmlRoot(ElementName = "component")] like this
 by `code`[XmlRoot("component")]
 and try   to add                  `code`ms.Position = 0;  in class xml just after `code`serial.Serialize(..).   `code`serial.Serialize(memory, objectToSerialize);
memory.Position = 0;

Comment: could you please write it in your answer its difficult to understand this code in comments ?

Comment: You can also remove [XmlRoot(ElementName = "parameter")]
from the class "parameter" because you've already states it in the "parameters" class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54039/discussion-between-user234839-and-alexein1).

Comment: Actually you can remove all the Xmlroot which you've already states as an xmlelement in "parameters" class

Comment: I commented all the XmlRoot in the class but still the same problem exists.

Comment: ok i see, try to change your serialization by this :                 using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    //Serialization
                    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ClassToSerialize));
                    xs.Serialize(ms, ObjectToSerialize);
                    ms.Position = 0;

                    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
                    xDoc.Load(ms);
                }

Comment: please write it in anser i am not able to understand here.

Comment: Do silverlight support XmlDocument ?

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'XmlDocument' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

Comment: iT IS NOT SUPPORTED by silverlight. and its equivalent in silverlight is XDocument from using System.Xml.Linq; and wheni do so it gives 1 error Error 1 Member 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(System.IO.Stream)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead CORREESPONDING TO " xDoc.Load(ms);"

Comment: and why you wanted me to change thecode like this ?

Comment: Because all is working fine when you deserialize? so I would have suspect the serialization

Comment: In serialization, I have done a testing like i put "public string Name { get; set; }" in my Parameters.cs(Not parameter.cs) and i done "           var pc = new Parameters() ;
            pc.Name = "shekharChk";" inside Main() in Xml.cs and it is showing <Name>ShekharChk<Name> in xml (with my code)

Comment: So I assume that you should have the same result with "Separator" element and that problem come from the "parameter" serialization. The xmlroot tag should be only marked in the "parameters" class because it's the root, keep it in the "parameters" class and remove all the others

Comment: As a conclusion from what i understand from your comment is:(1) Just put [xmlRoot] only in Parameters.cs (  [XmlRoot(ElementName = "parameters")]) remove from other place :I HAVE DONE IT IS STILL SAME.

Comment: wHEN I put pouse on "pc" in line  var xml = pc.ToXml(); (while debugging) it shows me Paramaeter (Null but with a plus sign),Separator (Null),Shekhar(Null). When i put mouse on Plus sign shown on Parameters, then it shows "static memebers" then it show "Non public Members" and then ""_emptyArray, {SliderLastTry.Parameter[0]}

Comment: Did you try in changing :

Comment: Did you try to change :        [XmlElement("parameter")] with[XmlArray("parameter")]    indeed, parameter is a collection

Comment: i HAVE done it.. how can it display the xml with out assigning items and values in the list :P

Comment: Have you foun a way with you issue ? :) What your xml looks like now ?