# WCF data contract serialization with custom XML attribute

Tags: wcf, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

Is there a possibility to get the response as the following since in my experience using data contracts does not allow to add an id inside an element (e.g.  ). Is there a way to achieve the following structure? Also notice that this is without a root tag.

```
<Number Id=”1”> 
<FName>1234567890ABC</ FName >
<Date>7/1/2012 12:00:00 </ Date >
</Number >
< Number Id=”2”> 
< FName >9876543210XYZ</ FName >
< Date >7/1/2012 12:00:00 </ Date >
</ Number >
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from this post: [How can you control .NET DataContract serialization so it uses XML attributes instead of elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591907/how-can-you-control-net-datacontract-serialization-so-it-uses-xml-attributes-in)

> . . . take a look at  XmlSerializerFormatAttribute which allows you to use
>   the XmlSerializer  for serialization.

and from same post

> You can do this with the DataContractSerializer - the answer is to take over the Xml serialization yourself by
>   implementing the IXmlSerializable interface. ...

This article can be also helpful: http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/

Comment: Is there a possibility to serialize IEnumerable in this way? (Using XML Serialization)

Comment: You can try to modify the code from linked post, lie  writer.WriteAttributeString("name", your_ienumerable.to_sting_in_some_way_you_want_it);

Comment: Can we add an XML attribute to the root tag? Ive been searching that for sometime now.

Comment: Also, there a root element that comes which i haven't defined and i'm clueless as to where it comes from.