# C# - Serializing private property as attribute (Data Contract)

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontract, datamember

After learning I can't serialize private properties in a class, I started using **DataContract** and **DataMember** annotations.

I have a private string property in my class that I would like to serialize as an attribute and not as an element.

```
[DataContract]
public class Channel
{
    private string m_Name = string.Empty;
    private DateTime? m_TxTime = null;

    [DataMember, XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Name;
        }
        set
        {
            m_Name = value;
        }
    }

    public DateTime? TxTime
    {
        get
        {
            return m_TxTime;
        }
        set
        {
            m_TxTime = value;
        }
    }

    [DataMember, XmlAttribute("txTime")]
    private string txTimeForSerialization
    {
        get
        {
            if (TxTime.HasValue)
            {
                return TxTime.Value.ToString("o");
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Trying to use the **DataMember** and **XmlAttribute** annotations together gave me this output:

```
<channel name="NAME">
   <TxTime>2017-03-26T13:15:56.8042989+03:00</TxTime>
</channel>
```

The result I want is this -

```
<channel name="NAME" txTime="2017-03-26T13:15:56.8042989+03:00" />
```

The way I serialized is by using the XmlSerializer -

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("channels.txt", FileMode.Create))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Channel));
    serializer.Serialize(fs, objectName);
}
```

Comment: `XmlSerializer` only serializes public fields and properties. Also, if you want to use it, you don't need `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes since they are used by `DataContractSerializer`.

Comment: `DataContractSerializer` does not use XML attributes.  See [How can you control .NET DataContract serialization so it uses XML attributes instead of elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/591907/3744182).  Implementing `IXmlSerializable` as shown below should work for both serializers.

Answer (score 0):

Create "wrapper" for your class which will be responsible for correct deserialization format (some kind of Facade pattern)

```
[DataContract]
public class ChannelData
{
    [DataMember, XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember, XmlAttribute("txTime")]
    public string txTimeForSerialization { get; set; }
}
```

You can put logic of creating serialization instance in `Channel` class, then responsibility will serialization logic will remain in Channel class - which keep encapsulation.

```
public class Channel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? TxTime { get; set; }

    public Channel()
    {
        Name = string.Empty;
        TxtTime = null;
    }

    public ChannelData ToSerialization()
    {
        var data = new ChannelData();
        data.Name = Name;
        data.txTimeForSerialization = TxTime.HasValue ? TxTime.Value.ToString("o") : null;
    }
}
```

With wrapper you don't need think about different "workarounds" for different formats, your "business layer" classes will stay "clear" and wrappers will handle formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with your current `Channel` class, you need to implement `IXmlSerializer` interface and its *WriteXml* method. That's the only way you can serialize private properties via `XmlSerializer`.

```
public class Channel : IXmlSerializable
{
    private string m_Name = string.Empty;
    private DateTime? m_TxTime = null;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Name;
        }
        set
        {
            m_Name = value;
        }
    }

    public DateTime? TxTime
    {
        get
        {
            return m_TxTime;
        }
        set
        {
            m_TxTime = value;
        }
    }

    private string txtTimeForSerialization
    {
        get
        {
            if (TxTime.HasValue)
            {
                return TxTime.Value.ToString("o");
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        //implement reader if needed...
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteAttributeString("name", this.Name);
        writer.WriteAttributeString("txtTime", this.txtTimeForSerialization);
    }
}
```

By implementing `IXmlSerializable` you don't need to use attributes anymore and your code for writing into *channels.txt* will remain the same:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("channels.txt", FileMode.Create))
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Channel));
    serializer.Serialize(fs, objectName);
}
```

Here is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Channel name="NAME" txtTime="2017-03-26T12:57:25.6780078Z" />
```