# How to add attribute in Datamember c#?

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

How to add attribute to data Member?

**Current datamember:**

```
 [DataMember(Order = 18, Name = "shippingAddress")]
  public SubscriptionAddressOut ShippingAddress { get; set; }
```

**This is my current output:**

```
            <b:shippingAddress>
                 <b:name>abcd</b:name>
             </b:shippingAddress>
```

**Required output:**

```
     <a:address type="shipping">
                <a:name>abc</a:name>
            </a:address>
```

Comment: Do you just want to add an attribute to an xml element from c# in code?

Comment: If you are using [tag:datacontractserializer] then this serializer does not support XML attributes, see [DataContract XML serialization and XML attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4858798/3744182) and [How can you control .NET DataContract serialization so it uses XML attributes instead of elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/591907/3744182).  You will need to switch to [`XmlSerializer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer) or implement [`IXmlSerializable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/280077/3744182).

Comment: If you are not using [tag:datacontractserializer] then could you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing how you are serializing your object?